# use more than a array in jquery post and get php result

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

i want to post many array to php page with jquery and get result but i cant give array in php page

> Notice: Undefined index: $name
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $type
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $value
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $size

the jquery code :

```
$('#ss').live('click', function () {
$("#main_login").html("<center>waiting plaese . . . .</center>");
    var name = [];
    var type = [];
    var size = [];
    var value = [];

    $(".name").each(function() {
        name.push($(this).val());
    });

    $(".type").each(function() {
        type.push($(this).val());
    });

    $(".size").each(function() {
        size.push($(this).val());
    });

    $(".value").each(function() {
        value.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: "name[]="+name+"&type[]="+type+"&size[]="+size+"&value[]="+value,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main_login').html(data);
            

        }
    });
```

the html code

```
<input type="text" class="name"  name="name[]" value="" />
<input type="text" class="value" name="value[]" value="" />
<input type="text" class="type"  name="type[]" value=""  />
<input type="text" class="size" name="size[]" value=""  /> 

<a href="#" id="ss">send</a>
```

the php code :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

$names = array(
   'name' => '$name',
   'size' => '$size',
   'value' => '$value',
   'type' => '$type',
);

foreach( $names as $key => $n ) {
  echo "
  The name is ".$name[$key]."
  The size is ".$size[$key]."
  The type is ".$type[$key]."
  The value is ".$value[$key]."
  ";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Many issues here....

Comment: You are essentially doing `$name['name']`/`$size['name']`/`$type['name']`/`$value['name']` and then `$name['size']`/`$size['size']`/`$type['size]`/`$value['size']` and then etc...

Comment: A summary of the text of the error

Comment: There is no reason to do the `$names = array(....)` and then `foreach( $names as $key => $n ) {...`. Just do the loop using one of your `$_POST` arrays, ie. `foreach( $name as $key => $val ) { ... }`. That will then map all the `$_POST` arrays using the `$key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JavaScript part, this line in the ajax call is problematic:

```
data: "name[]="+name+"&type[]="+type+"&size[]="+size+"&value[]="+value,
```

You are concatenating arrays, which will be converted to comma-separated strings. This is not what you'd want (think of individual values that already have commas). Instead use object notation. jQuery will deal with it:

```
data: {
    name: name,
    type: type,
    size: size,
    value: value
}
```

Secondly, in PHP this code is problematic:

```php
$names = array(
   'name' => '$name',
   'size' => '$size',
   'value' => '$value',
   'type' => '$type',
);
```

The single quotes around *$name* will just make it a literal string that is *$name* (not the variable, but the literal with *$* ... etc).

But, besides that, the above associative array *$names* is not really helping you. I would just drop the whole statement, and continue like this (notice *$name* in singular):

```php
foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
   echo "
    The name is ".$name[$key]."
    The size is ".$size[$key]."
    The type is ".$type[$key]."
    The value is ".$value[$key]."
  ";
}
```